# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'ontbijt' - Django QuerySet

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models, django-views

> My model:

```
class planner(models.Model):
       datum = models.DateField(unique=True)
       ontbijt = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       tussendoor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       lunch = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       tussendoor_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Amandelen')
       avondeten = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

> My view:

```
def voedingplanner_interface(request):
    dt_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    data_planning = planner.objects.filter(datum__gte=datetime.date.today())

    print (data_planning.ontbijt) < CAUSE !!!!
```

> My error:

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'ontbijt'
```

> My question:

I know I can return the models trough *str* (self) etc, but that way makes it hard for this program in the future.
As in HTML, I can just write {{dataplanning.ontbijt}} and it appears. The same way I want it in my backend. As far as I searched and study + my knowledge I didn't find an answer. Does someone have the solution for this one?

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) results in [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) which should be iterated

```
for plan in planner.objects.filter(datum__gte=datetime.date.today()):
    plan.ontbijt
```

If you expect only one result you could use [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get) instead

Comment: Hey, That solved it. Thank you for your help! I wish you a wonderfull day ;).

Comment: Never knew about this API reference. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet , it is  very helpful. Thank you